# QProcess curl and the github REST api

Tags: qt, curl, qt4, qt5, qprocess

I'm trying to use the GitHub REST API to create an issue in a repo. I'm using the following command:

```
curl -u "marcusbritanicus:pass" https://api.github.com/repos/marcusbritanicus/apitrial/issues -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@issue.json
```

This works perfectly as expected. However, when I use QProcess to execute the same command, I get `{"message": "Bad credentials", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

This is how I use `QProcess` (Python/Qt4 2.7.14/4.12.1 on Debian Sid):

```
>>> proc = QProcess()
>>> proc.setProcessChannelMode( QProcess.MergedChannels )
>>> args = [ "-u", "'marcusbritanicus:password'", "https://api.github.com/repos/marcusbritanicus/apitrial/issues", "-XPOST", "-H", "'Content-Type: application/json'", "-d@issue.json" ]
>>> proc.start( "curl", args )
>>> proc.waitForFinished()
>>> proc.readAll()
```

Is there some mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the quotes around your credentials(`''`), it is not necessary to use them if they are at the beginning and end of the argument.

```
proc = QProcess()
proc.setProcessChannelMode( QProcess.MergedChannels )
args = [ "-u", "marcusbritanicus:password", "https://api.github.com/repos/marcusbritanicus/apitrial/issues", "-XPOST", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d@issue.json" ]
proc.start( "curl", args )
proc.waitForFinished()
proc.readAll()
```